# Selenium/TestBench failure: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, google-chrome, vaadin, pom.xml, vaadin7

I tried to run the web application and launch it using google chrome but it shows an error and this is the exception that im getting. Im new to web development and i dont have experience on web development. This is fully following from vaadin tutorial and still im getting such error.

I hope someone can explain the problem here and the solution.

```
12:18:42.557 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as C:\Users\Abyss\.m2\repository\webdriver\chromedriver\win32\85.0.4183.87\chromedriver.exe
Sep 18, 2020 12:18:42 PM com.vaadin.testbench.parallel.ParallelTest setup
INFO: Did not find a configuration to run locally, on Sauce Labs or on other test grid. Falling back to running locally on Chrome.
Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689}) on port 14652
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Sep 18, 2020 12:18:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions (file:/C:/Users/Abyss/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sep 18, 2020 12:18:52 PM com.vaadin.testbench.ScreenshotOnFailureRule failed
INFO: Error screenshot written to: C:\Users\Abyss\Documents\Intellij Prgram\vaadin-crm\vaadin-crm\error-screenshots\loginAsValidUserSucceeds[ANY_Chrome_](com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.it.LoginIT).png

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-UIL9GAM', ip: '192.168.0.22', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 85.0.4183.102, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Abyss\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58803}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: de2db382831034a569b4913b37583b71

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchDriverProxy.get(TestBenchDriverProxy.java:66)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvste97_0._d24get(TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvste97_0.java)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.DriverInvocationHandler.invoke(DriverInvocationHandler.java:51)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvste97_0.get(TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvste97_0.java)
    at com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.it.AbstractTest.setup(AbstractTest.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.parallel.ParallelRunner$1.evaluate(ParallelRunner.java:468)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.parallel.ParallelScheduler$1.call(ParallelScheduler.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-UIL9GAM', ip: '192.168.0.22', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:489)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.commands.TestBenchCommandExecutor.waitForVaadin(TestBenchCommandExecutor.java:127)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.DriverInvocationHandler.waitForVaadinIfNecessary(DriverInvocationHandler.java:69)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.DriverInvocationHandler.invoke(DriverInvocationHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvste97_0.getScreenshotAs(TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvste97_0.java)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.ScreenshotOnFailureRule.failed(ScreenshotOnFailureRule.java:113)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.failedQuietly(TestWatcher.java:90)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.access$300(TestWatcher.java:52)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.parallel.ParallelScheduler$1.call(ParallelScheduler.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the error is related to the illegal reflective access warning.

Is your application running? TestBench requires your application to run while executing tests.

Comment: Thank you. Ive tried running the app first then run the test again. it worked. Can you explain it to me please. Source to read maybe. Thank you again.

Comment: @MuhdDanie With testbench, you simulate a user that visits your application using the browser. For this, the application needs to be running already. Olli described it nicely yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63932152/3441504). You can read [more about TestBench here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/testbench/testbench-overview.html) or more specifically about starting the application first [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/testbench/testbench-getting-started.html#running-tests)